# Can't make toast in onViewCreated()

Tags: java, android, android-studio

This is inside a fragment and I am learning fragment lifecycle. This is the code and my Toast does not work. Can anyone help me out?

```
 @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        *Toast.makeText(requireActivity(), "View Created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();*

        Button btn = view.findViewById(R.id.btn);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
//                Intent intent = new Intent(requireActivity(),MainActivity2.class);
//                startActivity(intent);
                frag = new Frag();
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container,frag).addToBackStack(null).commit();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: this is inside a fragment and I am learning fragment lifecycle. This is the code and my Toast does not work. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: paste your full fragment code and crash report if any crash

Comment: replace getActivity() with requireActivity()

Comment: already did that but didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Methods which would give you the context like getActivity(), getContext() would only work after onActivityCreated is called. As you are calling this in onViewCreated(), which I guess is called before onActivityCreated this would these API's would return null.

You can either try calling your toast from onActivityCreated, or will have to try out some way of passing context from your application class.

Comment: onActivityCreated is deprecated and now you use onViewCreated, he placed it in the right block but something else is the issue. https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment#onActivityCreated(android.os.Bundle)

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead of `getActivity()` or `requireActivity()`

```
Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "TEST TEST", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Also, check in your `onCreateView` if you inflated the layout like this:

```
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_blank, container, false);
}
```

If you don't provide a layout with `R.layout.fragment_layout` that could be the reason why it isn't working. But even without `getApplicationContext()` and only using `getActivity()` it should work. So maybe your problem is in the `onCreateView` method.